# Linux / Change ulimit -Hn

Tags: linux

When I do `ulimit -Sn`, I get 1024.

I change it with: `ulimit -n 4096`

and It changes to 4096.

How do I do the same process to `ulimit -Hn`

Answer (score 0):

Be root. Normal users can only decrease hard limits. From the bash manpage:

> A hard limit cannot be increased by a non-root user once it is set; a soft limit may be increased up to the value of the hard limit.

As root, you can for many distros configure the stack size limit (and other limits) for user sessions in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. This is used by `pam_limits` (google term):

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>

*               hard    stack          16384    # for example.
```

Note that this will only affect new sessions. The user will have to log out and in again.